# How to emulate fullscreen for a website?

Tags: browser, fullscreen, web-development, emulation

I've got a website that works only in fullscreen.

Its not due to compatibility issues, but the developer has made it in a way so that when we enter the website it automatically enters fullscreen, and when it we try to exit, the website comes to know about it and alerts the user. If user still exits the fullscreen, it redirects to other site. The developer doesn't want the user to use any other apps while using the website.

I mean I can't use that website if I exit fullscreen.

But this is a problem for me because I multitask a lot. I want to use this website, but it consumes a lot of time.

Is there a workaround (like browser settings) such that the website thinks its in fullscreen while I can use my other applications like Photoshop, Notepad++ etc?

P.S.: I use Windows-8.1. Also I don't want to use Virtual Machines.
I use these browsers- Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Opera Browser, Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to mind was Virtual Machine because those are easy, freely available and familiar to me but they are overkill for this purpose, so I understand you don't want to use them. Consider it a back-up plan if my other suggestion does not work because I don't what that app does to detect when you are no longer in full-screen.

What would probably be the best fit is to split your display into virtual displays, so that one half or a quarter of your screen appears as its own display and anything that becomes full-screen within it will only occupy that portion. You can try [Virtual Display Manager](https://www.ishadow.com/vdm/) or [Display Fusion](https://www.displayfusion.com).

Another thing to try is to connect your monitor twice to your computer! You need a dual-head display adapter with connectors that match 2 different ones on your display. This will make Windows think you have two and you will have to switch between the two using the *Input* button on your monitor, so the app will be full-screen and you will be able to switch back and forth but not see both the website and anything else simultaneously.